# Displaying in View values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following View in my program. It has more than one FloorNum, however when it displays it is only displaying first FloorNum. How can I loop it so that it displays values for all FloorNum where LocID=xx

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LocID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FloorNum)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RoomNum)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RoomStatus)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model ) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LocID)

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FloorNum)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoomNum)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoomStatus)
        </td>

        <td>
```

class for model is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace HC.Data
{
    public class Rooms
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int LocID { get; set; }
        public int FloorNum { get; set; }
        public int RoomNum { get; set; }
        public int RoomStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I can't change LocID to list because work is all done using RAD and at this time changing it would delay substantially.  I am just wondering if on display some loop can be placed to make it work.

Comment: Can you display what type your Model is?

Comment: One LocID has many Floors, hasn't it?

Comment: So you don't have any collection to iterate over. What do you expect from `foreach (var item in Model )` ?

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that you are passing a single value of 'Rooms' to the view, and the foreach loop is display the one room.  If you pass a List to the view the foreach loop will almost certainly work as you have it written.  But the DisplayFor might not because it would no longer be pointed to a single instance of a Rooms class but a list of rooms.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model is `List<Room>`:

```
@{
    List<int> floors = Model.Select(x => x.FloorNum).Distinct();
}
@foreach (var floor in floors)
{
    foreach(var room in Model.Where(x => x.FloorNum == floor))
    {
        ... your display helpers here...
    }
}
```

This is pseudo code, so some adjustments may be needed.